# How to add a timestamp to console output file in RubyMine

Tags: rubymine, jetbrains-ide

In RubyMine (and in other JetBrains products, I believe) there are Run/Debug Configurations, for which it is possible to save console output to a file:

[image: Console output filename]

Is it possible to add a timestamp to the filename, something like `$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly this is not possible. This really is meant to be for the console output when developing. While it might be understandable that you would prefer separate output file every time you run your code, it is more common to simply use some kind of logger.

If you would be running your command from commandline/term/cmd/iterm/xterm/shell you could leverage your OS to store the the output to file and even give you the timestamp for the filename.